# Responsive background "white board" image

Tags: html, css

Hi I'm trying to get a white board background image on a web-page without having to load a huge image for it.  I almost got it working however in a smaller resolution responsive version, the top image breaks resulting in it not being quite responsive.  How can i stop the breaking or is their a better way to do this? The following is the css for 3 separate divs:

```
.mission{
  width: 100%;
  padding: 50px;
  background-image: url("images/whiteboard_strip.jpg");
  background-size: 100%;
}

.missiontop{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url("images/whiteboard_top.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 80px;
}

.missionbottom{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url("images/whiteboard_bottom.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  padding-top: 81px;
}
```

Any help appreciated!

EDIT: HTML CODE

```
<div class="col-sm-12 servicecolumnone startAnimation animated missiontop" data-animate="slideInLeft"></div>
                    <div class="col-sm-12 servicecolumnone startAnimation animated mission" data-animate="slideInLeft">
                        <image src="activism/images/mission.png"></image>
                        <h4><span>Our Mission</span></h4>
                        <p>To promote and advance the highest levels of professional service in the teaching profession, and to represent and advance the just cause of teachers and their collective views of Government and Educational authorities at all levels within Belize and abroad, in order to promote and achieve the best possible standards of education and quality of life for all of our people.
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-12 servicecolumnone startAnimation animated missionbottom" data-animate="slideInLeft"></div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by the top image "breaks" resulting in it not being quite responsive? Also, are you able to provide links to the 3 images you are working with?

Comment: meaning there is a white space in between div with "missiontop" class and div with "mission" class.  Please note that missiontop and missionbottom classes are both empty divs

Comment: if it helps here is a link to how it looks:

http://i4.photobucket.com/albums/y149/belizeno/mission_responsive.png

Comment: here's a image of how it looks on full resolution: http://i4.photobucket.com/albums/y149/belizeno/mission.png

Comment: i think u can see the difference in gradient of the 3 images.  Hope it helps

Comment: please add your html

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using `background-image` to present a border around some content, I'd suggest switching instead to [`border-image`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-image); for example:

```
.mission {
  border-image: url(--path to file--) 30 30 round;
}
```

where the `30 30` instructs the browser to treat a 30px² area in the corners of the image file as the "border corner". The MDN article has a bunch of great examples which illustrate the point better than I can.

Note that IE11 is the first internet explorer version to support `border-image`.

If it's also important to "fill in the centre" with a background image, then using `background-size: cover` per [Rachel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32514928/2821583) would probably work best.

Comment: Thank you Jeremy, I will try both suggestions and see which one works best.  Will get back

Comment: this worked to perfection since there was really no need to fill the centre as you mentioned.  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use a medium image and set the background-size to `cover` instead of 100%. this way it will adjust in size depending on the screen resolution. See the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/7h19yrcb/1/) I have used bright images to highlight the effect.

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
}
.mission {
  text-align: center;
  color: green;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80%;
  background-image: url("http://www.thinkstockphotos.com.au/CMS/StaticContent/Hero/TS_AnonHP_462882495_01.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
}
.missiontop {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10%;
  background-image: url("http://www.thehindu.com/multimedia/dynamic/01662/THSRN_THAILAND_1662101g.jpg");
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-size: cover;
}
.missionbottom {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10%;
  background-image: url("http://www.goodlightscraps.com/content/nature/nature-images-63.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
h4 span {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: darkgreen;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="col-sm-12 servicecolumnone startAnimation animated missiontop" data-animate="slideInLeft"></div>
  <div class="col-sm-12 servicecolumnone startAnimation animated mission" data-animate="slideInLeft">
    <img src="activism/images/mission.png">
    <h4><span>Our Mission</span></h4>
    <p>To promote and advance the highest levels of professional service in the teaching profession, and to represent and advance the just cause of teachers and their collective views of Government and Educational authorities at all levels within Belize
      and abroad, in order to promote and achieve the best possible standards of education and quality of life for all of our people.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-12 servicecolumnone startAnimation animated missionbottom" data-animate="slideInLeft"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Since OP's images are actually providing borders, you'd need to handle the top and bottom parts differently to avoid distortions which would break the visual effect

Comment: Thank you Rachel! I'll give it a wack! Thanks for your great example